# Can't remove old SSH keys from connection Mac OS

Tags: macos, ssh, ssh-keys

Every time I connect via SSH, the agent will try non-existent keys:

```
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_xmss
...
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /Users//.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /Users/user/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
```

Only id_rsa exists, the rest has already been removed. I don't even remember some of them in the first place. On my ~/.ssh folder, I only have:

```
╰─➤  $ ls -a /Users/user/.ssh
.                   authorized_keys     id_ed25519_qemu.pub known_hosts.old
..                  config              id_rsa
.DS_Store           config.backup       id_rsa.pub
.id_rsa.pub.swp     id_ed25519_qemu     known_hosts
```

As you can see, the qemu key doesn't even get to be used by the agent. Entering `ssh-add -D` outputs `All identities removed`, but the keys are attempted anyway. And `ssh-add -L` gives me only `The agent has no identities.` I've checked on Keychain Access by searching for SSH and there is only `id_rsa` and three other .pem keys that are saved in a folder elsewhere.

How do I remove the non-existent keys?

Comment: Have you looked at `known_hosts`?

Comment: Doing `grep id_dsa ~/.ssh/known_hosts` returns nothing

Comment: what about id_rsa?

Comment: Hmm it also returns nothing. Am I searching for the wrong thing then?

Comment: Well, without actually giving the contents, what does your known_hosts file look like? If you're brave, back it up and delete it entirely and it should solve the problem. Oh also, show us your config file (being careful to remove any secret info)

Comment: I moved the file to known_hosts.old, it created a new one but the same keys are attempted. As for my config, I have the following general rule: `Host * \ XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth \    ForwardAgent yes `. Besides that, it's just username and hostname configurations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138490/discussion-between-barry-carter-and-specimen).

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't old keys. That's just how your system is set up to automatically look for different key types just in case you happen to generate keys of different types. Like, maybe you've been primarily using an RSA key, and then at some point you decide you like elliptic curve keys better, so you generate an EC key. With the system set up like this, you don't have to modify your SSH configs to start using your new EC key, you just have to generate a key with the default filename for that key type, and it just works.